# Bug with new top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

Once again, a picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for reporting! Fix for this is waiting in repo for next build so should be up in couple hours.

Comment: It was probably just a Z index issue, right?

Comment: @AndroidDev correct. new black topbar was basically rewritten from scratch. we tested it a lot internally and externally but there're still some bugs left probably.